# Getting Error during Release build with r8

Tags: android, android-r8

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
Library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient

I tried adding -keep class com.google.api.** { *; } to the proguard rules

```
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at dCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:81)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:325)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:304)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_8.0.46.java:0)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.N0.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:74)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.N0.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:27)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.N0.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:26)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:19)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.run(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:3)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.R8Tool.runR8(r8Tool.kt:324)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$Companion.shrink(R8Task.kt:699)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable.execute(R8Task.kt:773)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
    at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.x.e(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:2)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.T5.f(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.d7.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:59)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.W6.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:3)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.v.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:702)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.i4.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:37)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.y5.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:11)
    at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.L.f(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:25)
    at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.L.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:2065)
    at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.l0.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.L.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:1871)
    at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.L.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:1418)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:1279)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:158)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.b(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.N0.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:23)
    ... 34 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.E2.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:29)
        at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.L.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:1419)
        at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:1279)
        at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:158)
        at com.android.tools.r8.R8.b(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.N0.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:23)
        at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:19)
        at com.android.tools.r8.R8.run(R8_8.0.46_2ffa4e0571e5ebfa8c3310c54d5dda57b06b7af8069dc742e901fe496c3e13dd:3)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.R8Tool.runR8(r8Tool.kt:324)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$Companion.shrink(R8Task.kt:699)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable.execute(R8Task.kt:773)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$0(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:169)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
        at oue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient]


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 22s
60 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 54 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer below is copied from https://issuetracker.google.com/200069038#comment4.

So the cause of the error is:

1. `android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient` is on the library/bootclasspath given to R8.
2. `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` is on the program path given to R8.
   The reasons are:

- case 1. happens because of the `<uses-library>` and will allow using the http lib shipped on devices.
- case 2. happens because your app or its dependency pulls in a version of the apache http lib.

I think there are two ways to resolve this:

- Find and remove the dependency that is pulling in the apache http lib to the program (`./gradlew <yourapp>:dependencies` may be able to give insight to where that is).
- Remove the `<uses-library>` and ship the apache http library of your choosing with the program. If you do this and target devices that have the native http library always on their bootclasspath, you will need to repackage/jarjar/shadowjar the http library to some other namespace, otherwise any program lookup on those devices will classload parts of the lib natively and parts from your shipped version which will crash at runtime.

Also see https://issuetracker.google.com/200069038#comment5 for a concrete resolution of this issue.